# SOLR slave is doing full Copy as it was not able to Delete unused Index dir

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

When a slave replicates the index it creates a index directory with name format as 
`index.timestamp` next time when it replicates it tries to cleanup and create a new folder  with new time stamp  but in my case its not happening and everytime i see this warning and Slave trigger a fullCopy

`Unable to cleanup unused lucene index files so we must do a full copy instead`

Could anyone why slave is not able to clean up the unused index  files.

thanks

Comment: slave will keep only the copy of master indexes, not cleaning up by itself. It is strange, though, your master still keeps unused indexes. If you can test, backup your index and try "optimize" the core. and see whether you can replicate this issue in your slave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very difficult to answer without knowing your solr version.

From my experience, solr copies index files that is different (newer then timestamp). However, if your indexes are merged, then it will trigger full copy.

Here is some related tickets

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6640

** update 11/27/2017 **

this is a relevant part in 5x branch,

https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/branch_5x/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/IndexFetcher.java#L398-L418

```
try {
    IndexWriter indexWriter = writer.get();
    int c = 0;
    indexWriter.deleteUnusedFiles();
    while (hasUnusedFiles(indexDir, commit)) {
        indexWriter.deleteUnusedFiles();
        LOG.info("Sleeping for 1000ms to wait for unused lucene index files to be delete-able");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        c++;
        if (c >= 30) {
            LOG.warn("IndexFetcher unable to cleanup unused lucene index files so we must do a full copy instead");
            isFullCopyNeeded = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (c > 0)  {
        LOG.info("IndexFetcher slept for " + (c * 1000) + "ms for unused lucene index files to be delete-able");
    }
} finally {
    writer.decref();
}
```

So, you have more than 30 unused index files and this will trigger the warning message & full copy. 
I would try to optimize or merge indexes from the master and see whether fullCopy is replicated.

Comment: Is it traditional master/slave or solrcloud? I thought it was master/slave but your tag confuses me.

Comment: SOLR Version using is 5.2.1 and its traditional  Master/Slave setup. Most of the time i see the warning in log Saying *couldn't clean up the unused index dir and thus triggering the full copy replication*  any idea on how to avoid this

Comment: The link shared was informative but i don't think  its related to the problem what am facing.